# creating object from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object.

```
var x = {"id":"asc","metaid":"desc"}
```

I want to create another object which looks something like this.

```
[{id: {order:"asc"}},{metaid: {order:"desc"}}]
```

What I have already tried is this

```
const sc1 = [];
var def1 = {}
for (let key of Object.keys(obj)){
def1[key] = {order: obj[key]}
}
sc1.push(def1);
```

The above code doesn't give required output.
Need help with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Map the entries of the object to return an object with a computed property name:

```js
var x = {"id":"asc","metaid":"desc"};

const result = Object.entries(x)
  .map(([prop, order]) => ({ [prop]: { order } }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That's a computed property name - it puts a property on the object such that the property name is the expression inside the `[]`s

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#from`

```js
var x = {"id":"asc","metaid":"desc"};
let out = Array.from(Object.entries(x), ([prop, value]) => ({[prop]: {order: value}}));
console.log(out)
```